# Pre add data to app keychain before uploading to the app store

Tags: ios, keychain

Can I add some secrets to the app keychain before shipping it ?
If yes what is the right approach?

Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The keychain is accessed when the application is running, therefore you can't do anything before the app is released. You can add your secrets when the application is first run, but the app must be uploaded and available for the user before it can do this.

Check out the [Keychain programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1).